# About PocketSphinxAndroidDemo

Tags: android, ubuntu, cmusphinx

I follow this site : http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/. and at first it work normal. but when i cmd ndk-build at the file /jni/.
the error is display bellow:

```
Compile thumb  : sphinxutil <= sbthread.c
Compile thumb  : sphinxutil <= utf8.c
StaticLibrary  : libsphinxutil.a
SharedLibrary  : libpocketsphinx_jni.so

/home/tian/develop/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/
prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/tian/桌面/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o: in function nbest_s_hyp:/home/tian/桌面/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:793: error: undefined reference to 'new_Hypothesis'

/home/tian/develop/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/tian/桌面/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o: in function ps_decoder_s_getHyp:/home/tian/桌面/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:847: error: undefined reference to 'new_Hypothesis'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/tian/桌面/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/obj/local/armeabi/libpocketsphinx_jni.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Most likely you built the wrong version. Please make sure you downloaded sphinxbase snapshot and pocketsphinx snapshot as recommended by the above blog post. Please make sure you used swig-1.3, not swig-2.0.

Comment: yes, i use the SWIG Version 1.3.40,but it doesn't work normal

Comment: Please provide a full build log. Please make sure that pocketsphinx_wrap.c is recreated with swig. Please make sure you are using snapshot versions.

Comment: hello, when i execute ndk-build -B, it needn't swig.

Comment: I have solved it. but i don't know how i solve it.haha

Comment: Hi , i am also facing the same problem... could you please help me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437698/pocketsphinxandroiddemo-is-not-building-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Did you paste the absolute path of the pocketsphinx parent directory? 
Like /home/.../.../.../pocketsphinx
instead of 
~/../.../.../pocketsphinx

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Mehul: I wasn't able to comment on the question. I didn't want him staying stuck because I don't have enough reputation either.